# How to create javascript promise chain with array function?

Tags: javascript

I am facing a weired issue when creating a js promise chain.In promise,when I am using array function with (),I don'nt get the expected value.It give me the 'undefined' value in second then.

***Here is the js code:***

```js
let x = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('sonet970@gmail.com');
    }, 2000);
});

function y(email) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(email);
        }, 4000);
    });
}

x.then((res) => {
    y(res);
})
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

But when I didn't use the ()=>{} syntax inside the .then,I got the expected answer.

***Here is the example of wright code:***

```js
let x = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('sonet970@gmail.com');
    }, 2000);
});

function y(email) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(email);
        }, 4000);
    });
}

x.then((res) => y(res))
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Your arrow function implementation is returning the promise `y(res)`, but in your first example, you don't return the promise `y(res)`, so it isn't being used in your promise chain: `return y(res);`

Answer (score 3):

In order to chain promises you need to return Promise.
This sample works correctly

```
x.then((res) => y(res))
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

because `(res) => y(res)` means:

```
(res) => {
   return y(res)
}
```

and the result of y() promise is passed to the next `.then`
So to solve your code you need to write it in this way:

```
x.then((res) => {
    // do some calculations
    return y(res);
})
    .then((res) => {
        // result of y promise
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Returning something from a `function` using curly braces `{}` means that you need to use keyword `return` to return something:

```
x.then((res) => {
  return y(res);
});
```

Using arrow functions, if no curly braces added, the immediately value after `=>` is returned.

```
then((res) => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers.Now I understand,why my first code din't work.It all about array function,nothing w
ith promises!